# Problem with my internal microphone

Tags: microphone

My internal microphone works well in applications like obs but it works super badly in applications like Cheese (for camera) or jitsi, meet.google, web.whatsapp, etc ... I don't know how to solve this anymore, I need help please.

additional information: I have a notebook "Lenovo A9, 8gb ram, ssd 256 ...

$ cat /proc/asound/cards

0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
HDA ATI HDMI at 0xd3460000 irq 39

1 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
HD-Audio Generic at 0xd3464000 irq 40

Comment: if you have pavu installed, open pavu and under input tab try adjusting the mic input volume. a higher volume give lots of white noises

Comment: DavidCabral316, please paste your solution as an Answer (In the "Your Answer" section below). Edit your original question to remove the solution text and the word "Solved!!!" in the question text. Then you should select your own Answer as the solution that worked by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it !! I just went to pavucontrol, in the input i press in unlock icon tab, then just muted the front right channel and it started working perfect!